# Sencha 3D objects

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-charts

Has anyone been able to work with 3D graphs in Sencha Touch?

If so, an example would be appreciated.

Comment: I found this diferent framework http://www.winktoolkit.org/ , in the demo part in the seccion XYZ has some demos in 3D for web apps touch http://www.winktoolkit.org/documentation/wink/ , sencha has something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha has its own charting libaray

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/charts/

But I think they are 2d charts.

They also have another product name PhiloGL which is a weGL framework which will allow you create the 3d charts.

http://senchalabs.github.com/philogl/